# How do I get PHP command line to use a php.ini file when it is not using one?

Tags: php, command-line, ini

This is for a Mac OS X.  I need to put a line in the `php.ini` file for PHP 5.6 - however, I have found out from this:

```
php -r "php_ini_loaded_file();"
```

That PHP is *not using* an ini file!

OK, so that was a surprise... How do I either tell PHP to use an ini file, or add the line I would have added in that ini file?

Using `php --ini` gives me the same thing:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the command-line switches in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) or with the help switch:

```
php -h
```

I believe you want one of these:

```
-c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
-d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
```

Otherwise, PHP will search for the *php.ini* file according to the [documented rules](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php). I understand that CLI interface makes use of the `PHPRC` environment variable if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.  I typed

```
php --ini
```

which also told me that there was no config file, but it DID tell me the default directory was `/etc`.

So I did a `sudo nano /etc/php.ini`

and added a comment (starting with a `;`) and did `php --ini` again - and it showed the file was present!  Just to be sure, I added some illegal characters, and went back to `php --ini` which told me there was a parse error.

So it appears you can always add a php.ini file - even if it starts out blank.

Comment: This information is pretty interesting but, if I didn't miss anything, it explains how to have the file in the location where PHP already expects it, rather than instruct PHP to use a different file (which seems to be the question).

Comment: Re *"...tell me the default directory"*: What field/line? Was it the one with *"Configuration File (php.ini) Path"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved !!!

**It's about Symfony server** 
you need to know the path where Symfony are trying to catch .ini
so you can copy and paste your php.ini in there.

Use this cmd **symfony cloud:clear-cache** 
And check if it's done with **symfony check:req**

*Now you can see your .ini path displayed*

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: 
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\php.ini